# Live CSS editing (firebug+?)

Tags: css, firebug

Is there an editor similar to firebug in functionality that lets you edit the CSS directly from the browser and shows you the changes live, but ***also*** has the ability to save changes to the server through FTP or some other connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FireFile](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefile/) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I've never used it myself, but you could try the free trial of [***Skybound Stylizer***](http://www.skybound.ca/).

Here's a quote:

> Online CSS Editing
>   **Open any site, make
>   changes, then save back to the server
>   via FTP, SFTP, or a network share, or
>   others.**
>
> ..
>
> Stylizer's real-time CSS development
>   extends to 9 different integrated web
>   browsers. On Windows, Google Chrome,
>   Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8, and
>   Firefox 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 3.6 are
>   supported. On Mac, Safari is
>   supported.
>
> ..
>
> The Stylizer workflow couldn't be
>   easier. Just open up the URL or the
>   HTML page you want to edit, the style
>   sheets are automatically extracted
>   from the page, and you're ready to
>   start making changes.

Comment: Looks really cool, but not as user friendly as I would expect. Has a lot of great features that Firebug doesn't have though. FireFile was more suitable for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

the web developer toolbar for firefox allows you to do that -> https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

well.. it allows you to save the css but I'm not sure if it's through ftp. but you can use that in combination with [expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/)

[image]

Comment: please read my answer more carefully before downvoting !!!! you would have noticed I mentioned this!

Comment: I *did* notice. I simply downvoted because you are ignoring the original question by providing an answer that is not useful.

Comment: In my opinion it is useful quite enough not to be worth downvoting

Answer (score 1):

http://cssUpdater.com is what you really are looking for :)

Edit in FireBug, hit the "Sync now" button and reload your page.